# How to Get GCP Service Account SignedJWT so I can call a 3rd party service that accepts GCP auth

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I'm trying to get a GCP Service account signed JWT, so that I can send it to authenticate with HashiCorp Vault which has GCP auth enabled.  I'm trying to run this code locally and have a GCP service account key file downloaded and have the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env property set.

Here is my function:

```js
import { IAMCredentialsClient } from '@google-cloud/iam-credentials';

const getGcpSAToken = async() : Promise<string | undefined | null> => {
    
    const client = new IAMCredentialsClient();
    const nbf= Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const nat= nbf + (1000 * 60 *60);

    const signRequest = {
        name: `projects/-/serviceAccounts/${process.env['VAULT_SA']}`,
        delegates:[],
        payload : JSON.stringify({
            iss: process.env['VAULT_SA'],
            sub: process.env['VAULT_SA'],
            aud: `vault/${process.env['VAULT_ROLE']}`,
            iat: nbf,
            exp: nat
        })
    }
    const signResponse = await client.signJwt(signRequest);
    const signedJwt = signResponse[0].signedJwt;
    return signedJwt;
};
```

I get this error at runtime:

```
Uncaught Error Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
    at callErrorFromStatus (c:\mcc\sf\ai-epic-int-poc\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:33:26)
    at onReceiveStatus (c:\mcc\sf\ai-epic-int-poc\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:195:52)
    at onReceiveStatus (c:\mcc\sf\ai-epic-int-poc\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:365:141)
    at onReceiveStatus (c:\mcc\sf\ai-epic-int-poc\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:328:181)
    at <anonymous> (c:\mcc\sf\ai-epic-int-poc\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:188:78)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

I'm modeling this call after what others in my org have done with Java.  The docs [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/iamcredentials/2.0.2/google.iam.credentials.v1.IAMCredentials.html#signJwt1)
aren't great and I'm struggling to find a nodejs example to work from.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the token you request to be signed must expire within 12 hours, per Google's library.  I had some funky math going on where I was assuming my epoch times in `iat` and `exp` claims had milliseconds.  Also HashiCorp will not let us use a token that is good for more than 900 seconds.  The following code works to obtain a signedJWT for your GCP service account which you can use to login to HC vault that has GCP auth enabled.

```
const getGcpSAToken = async() : Promise<string | undefined | null> => {

    const client = new IAMCredentialsClient();
    const nbf= Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const nat= nbf + 899; // HC vault will only accept tokens that are good for less than 900 seconds...

    const signRequest = {
        name: `projects/-/serviceAccounts/${process.env['VAULT_SA']}`,
        payload : JSON.stringify({
            iss: process.env['VAULT_SA'],
            sub: process.env['VAULT_SA'],
            aud: `vault/${process.env['VAULT_ROLE']}`,
            iat: nbf,
            exp: nat
        })
    } as protos.google.iam.credentials.v1.ISignJwtRequest;
    const [response] = await client.signJwt(signRequest);
    const signedJwt = response.signedJwt;
    return signedJwt;
};
```